# How to insert a new xml element with update and replace with SQL Server Manangement Studio

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xsd, xquery

I have this XML:

```
<qrcode xmlns="http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Echeq>
    <echeqFamilyId>67c8590e-66fe-43e1-9124-a2163a6365df</echeqFamilyId>
  </Echeq>
</qrcode>
```

But I want to get this:

```
<qrcode xmlns="http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Echeq>
 <awardedVPoints>0</awardedVPoints>
    <echeqFamilyId>67c8590e-66fe-43e1-9124-a2163a6365df</echeqFamilyId>
  </Echeq>
</qrcode>
```

I try to get that result like this:

```
UPDATE[dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions]     
SET[QRCodeXml] = CAST(REPLACE(CAST([QRCodeXml] as nvarchar(max)), '',  '<awardedVPoints>0') AS xml) 
FROM [dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions] 
WHERE qrcode = 'newvcheq'
```

But nothing changed in the xml.

So what I have to change?

Thank you

Okay, so I tried this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(N'http://vital10.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd' AS ns)
UPDATE [dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions]
SET QRCodeXml = QRCodeXml.query('
    declare default element namespace "http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd";
    <qrcode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    {
        for $x in ns:/qrcode/*
        return (
          if (empty($x/../awardedVPoints)) then (<awardedVPoints> {"0"}</awardedVPoints>)
          else (), $x)
    }
    </qrcode>')
FROM [dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions]
WHERE qrcode = 'newvcheq'
```

But then I get this:

> Msg 9332, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
>   XQuery [dbo.QRCodeDefinitions.QRCodeXml.query()]: Syntax error near ':', expected 'where', '(stable) order by' or 'return'.

If I do this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions]
SET [QRCodeXml] = [QRCodeXml].query('
declare default element namespace "http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd";
<qrcode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
{
    for $x in /qrcode/*
    return (
        if (empty($x/../awardedVPoints)) then (<awardedVPoints> {"0"}</awardedVPoints>)
        else (), $x)
}
</qrcode>')
FROM [dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions]
WHERE qrcode = 'newvcheq'
```

Then I get this error:

> XML Validation: Invalid content. Expected element(s): '{http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd}ExternalUrl','{http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd}Platform','{http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd}Image','{http://vital10.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd}Location','{http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd}Echeq','{http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd}Video'. Found: element '{http://vital10.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd}awardedVPoints' instead. Location: /*:qrcode[1]/*:awardedVPoints[1].

So what I have to change? Thank you

Table design. So this is the details of the table. with all the table fields

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions]
(
    [QRCode] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedOn] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ValidUntil] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [LastScannedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [TotalScanned] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [MaxAllowedToScan] [bigint] NULL,
    [MaxAllowedToScanByParticipant] [bigint] NULL,
    [ScanFrequency] [bigint] NULL,
    [ScanFrequencyType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ActionType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [QRCodeXml] [xml](CONTENT [dbo].[QRCodeSchema-2019-07-23]) NULL,
    [PublishState] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_QRCodeDefinitions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QRCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [PublishState]
GO
```

So this has to be the correct answer:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions]
SET QRCodeXml = QRCodeXml.query('
declare default element namespace "http://vital10.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd";
<qrcode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
{
    for $x in /qrcode/*
    return (
        if (empty($x/../awardedVPoints)) then (<awardedVPoints>{"0"}</awardedVPoints>)
        else (), $x)
}
</qrcode>')
FROM[dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions]
WHERE qrcode = 'newvcheq';
```

Comment: Please clarify what database is in use: mySQL or MS SQL Server.

Comment: MS SQL Server. that is the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.
It is using XQuery and its FLWOR expression.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, QRCodeXml XML, qrcode NVARCHAR(256));
INSERT INTO @tbl (QRCodeXml, qrcode) VALUES
(N'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<qrcode xmlns="http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Echeq>
        <echeqFamilyId>67c8590e-66fe-43e1-9124-a2163a6365df</echeqFamilyId>
    </Echeq>
</qrcode>', 'newvcheq');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

UPDATE @tbl
SET QRCodeXml = QRCodeXml.query('
declare default element namespace "http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd";
<qrcode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
{
    for $x in /qrcode/Echeq
    return <Echeq>
    {
        if (empty($x/awardedVPoints)) then
            (element awardedVPoints {"0"}, $x/*)
        else $x/*
    }
    </Echeq>
}
</qrcode>')
FROM @tbl
WHERE qrcode = 'newvcheq';

-- after
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

> Output

```
<qrcode xmlns="http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Echeq>
    <awardedVPoints>0</awardedVPoints>
    <echeqFamilyId>67c8590e-66fe-43e1-9124-a2163a6365df</echeqFamilyId>
  </Echeq>
</qrcode>
```

Comment: Oke, of course thank you!! But I have the table already, and the xml is part of a data row

Comment: @NiceTobeBottleInfinity, the proposed solution is handling a mock table `@tbl`. You just need need to  use your real table.

Comment: @NiceTobeBottleInfinity, please edit your post again, and provide a DDL for your table. Otherwise, it is not clear what is that column in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @NiceTobeBottleInfinity, I modified the answer accordingly. But it seems that the **QRCodeXml** column is enforced by the XSD Schema. That's why you are getting XML validation errors.

Comment: oke, but there is still standing @tbl, but oke that has to be then [dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions]

Comment: @NiceTobeBottleInfinity, do you know what to do next? You need to add the rest of the XML elements. The ones that the XSD is telling you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215756/discussion-between-nicetobebottleinfinity-and-yitzhak-khabinsky).

Comment: @NiceTobeBottleInfinity, I updated the proposed solution.